Finding specific application from location running, not just the application.exe?
I want a way of running and checking two of the same application.exe's using two different batch scripts, (in case they crash). In order to do this, I need to check each one individually based on the path the .exe came from.
My current code looks like this:
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq TimeLoopServer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "TimeLoopServer.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :PULSE

This worked great, it would detect if it was running in Windows, and if not it would reboot.
But now I want to run a second instance from a different directory, so my thinking is I can set the directories like this:
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq C:\ServerOne\TimeLoopServer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "C:\ServerOne\TimeLoopServer.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :PULSE

But this doesn't seem to detect the pathed executable.
Is there a better way to tackle this?
The applications will look the same in the Task Manager and the only difference is where the file was launched from.

You state that you're running each from the batch file too, but have only shown code for how you're checking them with tasklist.exe. Unless you provide the code you are using for running them too, you have not given us sufficient information to offer reasonable ways of achieving the task.

I think you're have more luck, using wmic, something like:
wmic process where caption="TimeLoopServer.exe" get commandline

=> The commandline might indicate the directory from where the process is run, isn't that what you're looking for?

Note: wmic is depreviated and not available with a new Win11 installation.

@Stephan: What is wmic replaced by?

Sadly there is no replacement in cmd (and there will be none, as cmd itself is depreciated. It's official successor is PowerShell, which has its own method to access WMI).

@Stephan, do you know when it became unavailable? I ask because I've just clean installed Windows 11 Home, 23H2 build 22631, on a PC, and WMIC worked immediately without any preconfiguration.

@Compo: sorry, I don't know. It's what I read here in comments. After a short research it seems it's excluded in Dev versions only source and related
